# Efficient code for using lots of buttons on a form

Tags: c#, forms

My question is less about a problem and more about knowing if there is a more efficient way of implementing my program (a currency converter) I am new at C# so I have used what I know to make this code but as you can see if the converter had to cover more things the code would get ridiculously long so I was wondering is there any better/ more efficient way of doing this? (Sorry there is no pic of the form; I don't have high enough rep to add one).

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace _158._212_assignment_2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private double amountToConvert = 0;
            private string convertingTo = "";
            private string convertingFrom = "";
            public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void NZDOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from: NZD";
            convertingFrom = "NZ";
        }

        private void AUDOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from: AUD";
            convertingFrom = "AU";
        }

        private void EUROC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from: EUD";
            convertingFrom = "EU";
        }

        private void GBPOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from: GBP";
            convertingFrom = "GB";
        }

        private void CADOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from: CAD";
            convertingFrom = "CA";
        }

        private void USDOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from: USD";
            convertingFrom = "US";
        }
        //Buttons for the currency you are converting to
        private void NZDCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: NZD";
            convertingTo = "NZD";
        }

        private void AUDCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: AUD";
            convertingTo = "AUD";
        }

        private void EURCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: EUR";
            convertingTo = "EUR";
        }

        private void GBPCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: GBP";
            convertingTo = "GBP";
        }

        private void CADCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: CAD";
            convertingTo = "CAD";
        }

        private void USDCC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: USD";
            convertingTo = "USD";
        }

        private void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double check;
            string Amount = currencyInput.Text;
            bool result = double.TryParse(Amount, out check);//checks if user input is a integer
            if (result)//if input is a integer the code proceeds
            {
                inputWarning.Text = ("");//removes previous error message if it was triggered
                if (convertingFrom == "NZ")
                {
                    amountToConvert = double.Parse(Amount);
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert / 1.36;
                }
                else if (convertingFrom == "AU")
                {
                    amountToConvert = double.Parse(Amount);
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert / 1.31;
                }
                else if (convertingFrom == "GB")
                {
                    amountToConvert = double.Parse(Amount);
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert / 0.68;
                }
                else if (convertingFrom == "EU")
                {
                    amountToConvert = double.Parse(Amount);
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert / 0.95;
                }
                else if (convertingFrom == "CA")
                {
                    amountToConvert = double.Parse(Amount);
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert / 1.28;
                }
                else if (convertingFrom == "US")
                {
                    amountToConvert = double.Parse(Amount);
                }
                else
                {
                    convertFromWarning.Text = "Please select the currency you are converting from";
                }

                if (convertingTo == "USD")
                {
                    output.Text = amountToConvert.ToString("F2");
                }
                else if (convertingTo == "CAD")
                {
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert * 1.28;
                    output.Text = amountToConvert.ToString("F2");
                }
                else if (convertingTo == "NZD")
                {
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert * 1.36;
                    output.Text = amountToConvert.ToString("F2");
                }
                else if (convertingTo == "AUD")
                {
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert * 1.31;
                    output.Text = amountToConvert.ToString("F2");
                }
                else if (convertingTo == "GBP")
                {
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert * 0.68;
                    output.Text = amountToConvert.ToString("F2");
                }
                else if (convertingTo == "EUR")
                {
                    amountToConvert = amountToConvert * 0.95;
                    output.Text = amountToConvert.ToString("F2");
                }
                else
                {
                    convertToWarning.Text = "Please select the currency to convert to";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                inputWarning.Text = " Please enter a valid amount";
            }
        }

        private void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            amountToConvert = 0;
            convertingTo = "";
            convertingFrom = "";
            CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to:";
            OCDisplay.Text = "Converting from:";
            output.Text = ("");
            currencyInput.Text = ("");
            inputWarning.Text = ("");
            convertToWarning.Text = ("");
            convertFromWarning.Text = ("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"namespace _158._212_assignment_2"_ -  _[Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Yes, there is a way to shorten your code. I suggest you research generic event handlers.

Comment: I would recommend a class and a data structure that allows you to fetch all this information using function calls.  Dictionaries are great for fast look-up and you can calculate the amounts without having to go through each type.  The class should know the conversion rates for each currency

Comment: Whenever you have a lot of very similar "things" to work with, you'll probably make you life easier if you use [lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). And if you need quick access to one item based on some unique property (like the "country code" values you assign to `convertingFrom` and `convertingTo`), you might want to look into [dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xfhwa508.aspx). And to group related information together (like country code, currency unit code, currency factor to base unit and so on), you probably want to create your own little class.

Comment: @MickyDuncan The problem is solved I was simply asking for any way too make it more efficient in the event that I need to make a larger program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        convertingFrom = (sender as Button).Text.Substring(0, 3);
        CCDisplay.Text = "Converting to: " + convertingFrom;
    }
```

You can add this eventhandler to all your buttons, it will take the first 3 characters off the buttons name and at it to the string.

Edit: Just noticed you require a From and To. For nice readable code do as Simon suggests and create another similar handler.

Comment: And possibly create another similar with "from".

Comment: Did you mean `CCDisplay.Text` instead of `CCDisplay.Name`?

Comment: @horHAY would there be a way for me to use                                                `convertingFrom = (sender as Button).Text.Substring(0, 3);`                         but have it outside the button code block so I only need the code once but whichever button is pressed it will update?

Comment: @JulienPowell You only need use this code one, as long as each button has this specific event handler.